# How to always listen to SMS android

Tags: android, service, sms, broadcastreceiver

Basically, I'm trying to make an app that always listens to new `SMS`.
The point is, i have made a Receiver that will auto-start at device boot, and it can also listen for new SMS, but only if the app is opened, if i close it, then it doesn't work anymore.
Here is my Service calling a BroadCastReceiver:

```
public class ServiceCommunicator extends Service {
private SMSReceiver mSMSreceiver;
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
private boolean receiverAlive = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    //SMS event receiver
    mSMSreceiver = new SMSReceiver();
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mSMSreceiver, mIntentFilter);
}

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public SmsMessage messages[] = null;

    private void showNotification(Context context, String sms) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText(sms);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                messages = null;
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    String sms = "";
                    String mobile = "34821049283";

                    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                        SmsMessage tmp = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        String senderMobile = tmp.getOriginatingAddress();

                        if (senderMobile.equals(mobile)) {
                            sms = tmp.getMessageBody();
                            showNotification(context, sms);

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception caught", e.getMessage());
        }

        receiverAlive = false;
        mSMSreceiver = new SMSReceiver();
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(mSMSreceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }
}
```

And here is my MainClass

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static SmsMessage[] messages = null;
    public static Activity mActivity = null;
    public static String mobile = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        mActivity = this;
        mobile = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMobile)).getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceCommunicator.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined this broadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register your `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest, using a `<receiver>` element, instead of using `registerReceiver()`.

Note that:

- You still will not get all SMS messages, as SMS broadcasts are ordered, and some receiver with higher priority than yours can abort the broadcast
- Your receiver will not work when first installed on a device, until the user launches an activity of yours, or something else explicitly runs one of your components

Also, note that [Android 4.4 significantly overhauled how the SMS process works](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html), so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look this GIT project

https://github.com/vivdub/DynamicSMSReceiver

This one just do exactly what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined this `BroadcastReceiver` in `AndroidManifest.xml`?
You don't need to use receiver in your code if you are registering for system event. It will automatically be called when event occurs. So remove you `BroadcastReceiver` form `Service` and put it in `AndroidManifest.xml` and just chill.